# Why is iisexpress crashing my application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-express

I have a problem and I don't know how to solve it or why I have it.
I have an application and I want to use iisexpress. I made the necessary changes like:
[image: server settings]

and this:

[image: application properties]

and without any errors when I run the application I get this:
[image: Application erros]

I followed this [link](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2011/01/03/vs-2010-sp1-beta-and-iis-developer-express.aspx) on how to use iis express.

Do you have any idea why is this happening?
Thank you

Comment: Do you have a heavy process in your website? and is it working with default settings of iisexpress?

Comment: If I uncheck the 'Use IIS Express' checkbox the application works fine. I don't think I understand your question sorry

Comment: Do you have a local https certificate? I thought that was needed to run applications on https...

Comment: If I understand correctly if I use IIS Express I don't need a local certificate anymore. That I was reading into the link that I follow.

Comment: Have you tried setting the IIS Url to be http and then enabling SSL on the settings?

Comment: After I restart the computer it works. Thanks